# Calculate the Price High and Low MySql query results

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there any can figure out on how to query the below image as a sample result,

What I want is to calculate the Price from yesterday compare to the price today order by date, if the price higher than yesterday then calculate the difference vise versa.

```
CREATE TABLE `pricing` (
  `prc_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pdo_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_entry` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_bin;

--
-- Dumping data for table `pricing`
--

INSERT INTO `pricing` (`prc_price`, `pdo_price`, `date_entry`) VALUES
(100, 100, '2022-04-01'),
(200, 200, '2022-04-02'),
(150, 100, '2022-04-03'),
(200, 100, '2022-04-04'),
(200, 250, '2022-04-05'),
(150, 150, '2022-04-06');
COMMIT;
```

Here SQLfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27f796f/1/0

This is the Sample Result

[image]

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE YourTableName;` for each table, and paste it into the questions as text (NOT A PICTURE). 
An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. 
If at all possible create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with the schema defined and some test data provided. 
Also a view of your expected output based on the table data you show as an example.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27f796f/1/0

Comment: is this possible in SQL